# How to display random photos from dogs and cats dataset?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to construct a CNN using the Microsoft cats and dogs dataset in Jupyter notebook. Right now the code below inspects the first nine dog pictures. How do I make it such that it randomly selects 9 dog photos to display in a 3x3 plot?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot 
from matplotlib.image import imread

folder = '/Users/sujiaying/Downloads/dogs-vs-cats/train/'

for i in range(9):
    pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    filename = folder + 'dog.' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    image = imread(filename)
    pyplot.imshow(image)

pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many dog pictures there are, you can use numpy!

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
numbers = rng.choice(numDogs, size=9, replace=False)
```

and then just use

```
for i in numbers:
```

instead of

```
for i in range(9):
```

If you don't want to use numpy then something like this will work

```
numbers = []
while True:
    num = random.randint(0, numDogs)
    if num not in numbers:
        numbers.append(num)
    if len(numbers) == 9:
        break
```